# Appropriate time to open stream during decompression of a file to be passed to a worker pool

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, compression

This may be more of a theoretical question.  I have a scenario wherein there is a compressed file (~2 GB) that gets decompressed into a larger file (~22GB).  This process takes roughly 20 minutes, which in turn means I am wasting about 19 minutes and 59 seconds every time this process gets run.  My question is the following:  Is it possible to open up a stream from the file that is being decompressed and pass the information to a separate program that will manipulate the data?  Essentially every line in the file is a record, but I have been unable to find a technique to discover when a line has been fully decoded during decompression.  General algorithms or Java libraries are of value.

Comment: I don't quite get the question.  What do you mean by "I have been unable to find a technique to discover when a line has been fully decoded during decompression"?  As you decompress, you obviously get the decompressed data.  So if you know the structure of your data, then you know when your records end.  Also I don't understand "I am wasting about 19 minutes and 59 seconds every time this process gets run".  Does this mean that your application is decoding 22 GB every time it wants to process a single record somewhere in that 22 GB?

Comment: @MarkAdler No it is not decompressing to find a single record this process runs every few hours with fresh data.  The confusion I have is does decompression go top to bottom or does it do some type of seeking where the data comes out randomly.

Comment: Decompression operates serially from beginning to end.  What is it exactly that you want to do?  Do you want to just access some data in the middle?

Comment: @MarkAdler Essentially I want to know when I reach the end of a line within the file that way I can correctly send it to a buffer.  I want to read all the data in and process it line by line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`java.util.zip`](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/)'s [`GZIPInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) to read the gzip file sequentially.  Then you can implement your own buffering and extract lines, or use [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) with the `readLine` method.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is easy.  In unix, you might do

```
bzcat compressedfile.bz2 | mainprogram
```

Then your mainprogram can read the decompressed stream on standard input.  Similar command-line programs exist for zip and gzip.

If the main program needs to read from a file instead of standard input, use a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).

If you're on Windows, there may or may not be similar tools.